# Laravel split request into multiple requests

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form with a lot of inputs. To organise the request, the inputs have different arrays. For example here a some input fields:

```
<input id="title" type="text" class="form-control" name="company[title]" required>
<input id="foundingYear" type="text" class="form-control" data-format="date" name="company[foundingYear]" required>
<input id="phone" type="number" class="form-control" name="entrepreneur[phone]" required>
```

Every model has a function called `shortEdit` that looks basicly like this:

```
public function shortEdit($request)
{ 
    $request->has('street') ? $this->street = clean($request->street) : null;
    $request->has('housenumber') ? $this->housenumber = clean($request->housenumber) : null;
    $request->has('city') ? $this->city = clean($request->city) : null;
    $request->has('country') ? $this->country = clean($request->country) : null;
    $request->has('phone') ? $this->phone = clean($request->phone) : null;
    $request->has('email') ? $this->email = clean($request->email) : null;
    $request->has('facebook') ? $this->facebook = clean($request->facebook) : null;
    $request->has('twitter') ? $this->twitter = clean($request->twitter) : null;
    ...
}
```

Now I thought I could call this functions like this insode my controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    ...
    $company->shortEdit($request->company);
    $entrepreneur->shortEdit($request->entrepreneur);
}
```

The `shortEdit` functions work perfect if I just call them with `$request` and in the request is only stuff for the model.

However, if I call them with the array, all functions that you can apply to a request (e.g. `$request->has()`) don't work anymore. So I thought is it possible to split the request into new requests and call with them the `shortEdit` functions?

Answer (score 0):

Do note that if you are to call them with the array you have to do it this way

```
$request->has('array_name.*');
```

the asteriks means all item in the array or you can do it this way if you know the key

```
$request->has('array_name.key_name');
```

but if you want to split a request you can by creating a new request object like this

```
$request2 = new Request([
  'key_name'=>'value',
  'another_keyname'=>'value',
]);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I found a solution that works:

I just have to check in every `shortEdit` function, if `$request` is an array. If so, I create a new request with that array:

```
if(is_array($request)) {
    $request = new Request($request);
}
```

Now I can work with `$request` as a request.